# Getting org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id error in Cucumber feature

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am using Selenium+Cucumber+TestNG and I am trying to close and open a new browser in between my feature. That is my requirement as there is no logout feature present in my application. Below is my code.

```
@Regression @Recall
  Scenario: Validate workflow with Recall from Closed tab
    Given User launch the "MISToolkit" application on browser
    When "approver" logs in to application
    Then "MISToolKit" page should appear
    Then User navigates to "ResearchTicketDashboard" page
    Then User navigates to WorkQueue on Research Ticket Dashboard Page
 And I "close" the browser for logging in as another analyst
    When User launch the "MISToolkit" application on browser
    When "analyst" logs in to application
```

Below is the step definition for And I "close" the browser for logging in as another analyst.

```
@Then("I {string} the browser for logging in as another analyst")
    public void closeTheSessionForLoggingInAsOtherAnalyst(String mode) {
        researchTicketDashboardPage.clearBrowserStorage(mode);

    }
```

And inside the clearBrowserStorage method I am trying to close the browser and open it again.

```
 driver.close();
 Base.initializeBrowserSetup();
```

I am getting following error.

```
When User launch the "MISToolkit" application on browser           # stepDefinitions.LoginPageStepDefinitions.userLaunchTheApplicationOnBrowser(java.lang.String)
      org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

driver.close() kills the session if there is only one browser open
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/close-browser-in-selenium

You will need to create a new session after closing the original driver.